# How to detect dash or underscore in datetime string to use in strptime?

Tags: python, regex, datetime

I have several thousand files which feature datetime in their file name.
Sadly the devider between the datetime blocks are not always the same.
Example:

- Data_trul-100A1-Berlin_2019-01-31_150480.dat
- Data_tral-2000B2-Frankf-2018_02_27-190200.dat
- Data_bash-300003_Hambrg_2017-04-12_210500.dat

I managed to find the datetime part in the string with a regular expression

```
import re

strings = ['Data_trul-100A1-Berlin_2019-01-31_150430.dat', 
           'Data_tral-2000B2-Frankf-2018_02_27-190200.dat', 
           'Data_bash-300003_Hambrg_2017-04-12_210500.dat']

for part_string in strings:
    match = re.search('\d{4}[-_]\d{2}[-_]\d{2}[-_]\d{6}', part_string)
    print(match.group())
```

However, now I am stuck to convert the group to datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), "%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S")
```

because I need to specify dashes or underscores.

I came up with the following solution to just replace it, but that feels like cheating.

```
for part_string in strings:
    part_string = part_string.replace('-',"_")
    match = re.search('\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{6}', part_string)
    date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), "%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S")
    print(date)
```

Is there a more elegant way? Using regex to find the divider and pass it on to strptime?

Comment: Well, your solution works as expected, there is no cheating. You should normalize the input and `replace` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your regular expression to find 4 separate elements

```
match = re.search('(\d{4})[-_](\d{2})[-_](\d{2})[-_](\d{6})', part_string)
```

Then combine them into one standard string format

```
fixedstring = "{}_{}_{}_{}".format(match.groups())
date = datetime.strptime(match.group(), "%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S")
```

Of course at this point you could just split the HHMMSS part of the time into their own elements and build the datetime object directly,

```
m = re.search('(\d{4})[-_](\d{2})[-_](\d{2})[-_](\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})', part_string)
date = datetime.datetime(year=m.group(0), 
                         month=m.group(1), 
                         day=m.group(2), 
                         hour=m.group(3), 
                         minute=m.group(4), 
                         second=m.group(5))
```